# Updated RestSharp to 106.2.2 and now getting error

Tags: c#, restsharp

Updated RestSharp to 106.2.2 and now getting error

> "Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=106.2.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

It was installed via `nuget` as a dependant package by `Atlassian.SDK`. This is `v10.2.2`.

It was all working before I updated them and I have no idea what version I did have working.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. Had to uninstall the Atlassian.SDK package along with Newtonsoft.Json and then RestSharp. I then re-added the Atlassian.SDK package back along with it's dependencies Newtonsoft.Json and then RestSharp and it worked again.